# Repeated keywords to use to format/ convert structure EDI/BAYPLIE files

Tags: notepad++, editor, edi, ultraedit, edifact

Is it possible or allowed to format the  EDIFACT / BAYPLIE file when there are same repeated keywords eg ? *(**RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN +**)   opening that in editors (Notepad++ or UltraEdit)  and convert /format structure each separate new lines?  

Sample from editor extract for 3 containers as below:

`RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN +GESU6445322 45G0 + ++ 0 + + 5'NAD CA + EMC: 172: 147 20'LOC + + 0,781,584 + 5'MEA :: WT ++ KGM: 13400'LOC + 9 + + 11 + CNNBO'LOC DEHBG 'RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN +ZCSU8245400 45G0 + ++ 0 + + CA + 5'NAD ZIM 172: 147 20'LOC + + 0,781,586 + 5'MEA :: WT ++ KGM: 12300'LOC + 9 + + 11 + CNNBO'LOC DEHBG 'RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN +TCNU8547134 45G0 + ++ 0 + + CA + 5'NAD ZIM 172: 147 20'LOC + + 0,781,588 + 5'MEA :: WT ++ KGM: 07900'LOC + 9 + + 11 + CNNBO'LOC DEHBG 'RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN + ...`


In final result after converting the lines can be displayed in more easier visual way and start


`RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN +GESU6445322 45G0 + ++ 0 + + 5'NAD CA + EMC: 172: 147 20'LOC + + 0,781,584 + 5'MEA :: WT ++ KGM: 13400'LOC + 9 + + 11 + CNNBO'LOC DEHBG '
RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN +ZCSU8245400 45G0 + ++ 0 + + CA + 5'NAD ZIM 172: 147 20'LOC + + 0,781,586 + 5'MEA :: WT ++ KGM: 12300'LOC + 9 + + 11 + CNNBO'LOC DEHBG '
RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN +TCNU8547134 45G0 + ++ 0 + + CA + 5'NAD ZIM 172: 147 20'LOC + + 0,781,588 + 5'MEA :: WT ++ KGM: 07900'LOC + 9 + + 11 + CNNBO'LOC DEHBG 'RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN +`


How to make in Notepad++ or Ultraedit editors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=.)\bRFF \+ BM: 1'EQD \+ CN \+`
- Replace with: `\n$0`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=.)                     : Look behind, make sure we ahave a character before
\b                         : word boundary, to not match xxxRFM
RFF \+ BM: 1'EQD \+ CN \+  : literally (+ have to be escaped as it is a special character)
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n                  : linebreak, you could use "\r\n"
$0                  : content of group 0 (ie the whole match)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN +GESU6445322 45G0 + ++ 0 + + 5'NAD CA + EMC: 172: 147 20'LOC + + 0,781,584 + 5'MEA :: WT ++ KGM: 13400'LOC + 9 + + 11 + CNNBO'LOC DEHBG '
RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN +ZCSU8245400 45G0 + ++ 0 + + CA + 5'NAD ZIM 172: 147 20'LOC + + 0,781,586 + 5'MEA :: WT ++ KGM: 12300'LOC + 9 + + 11 + CNNBO'LOC DEHBG '
RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN +TCNU8547134 45G0 + ++ 0 + + CA + 5'NAD ZIM 172: 147 20'LOC + + 0,781,588 + 5'MEA :: WT ++ KGM: 07900'LOC + 9 + + 11 + CNNBO'LOC DEHBG '
RFF + BM: 1'EQD + CN + ...
```

Comment: Very useful  code not only for EDIFACT /BAYPLIE Thanks for explanation 3rd line a special character to be escaped   with "\"- >"\+" - I  removed only spaces between `RFF \+ BM: 1'EQD \+ CN \+`  `RFF \+BM:1'EQD \+CN \+`   to directly use  Ctrl+C  Ctr+V-Regards